# Kinds of improper wordings or self-conflicting terms which can undermine the effect of an agreement

Tags: contract-law, tenant

When there’re improper wordings or self-conflicting terms in an agreement, what factors should be considered to determine whether the effect of the agreement is undermined?

For example:
A tenancy agreement has been created between a landlord A and a tenant B. B pays the rents to A to rent the place. But one (the first) clause in the agreement read: **Outlines the arrangement and terms of the tenant to rent as a subtenant of the landlord through a sublease of the premises of ADDRESS OF THE PLACE**

In this case, B pays the rents to the landlord to rent the place, he/she should be considered as a tenant, but the above-mentioned clause states that the tenant rent as a subtenant, which may cause confusions. But is that confusing enough such that the enforceability of the agreement is undermined?

Answer (score 2):

> is that confusing enough such that the enforceability of the agreement is undermined?

No. Inaccurate labels are unlikely to prevent the parties and the fact-finder from ascertaining the intent and legal implications of the agreement. Nor can the improper labels overcome the *non sequitur* of a landlord leasing directly to a "subtenant", that is, with no underlying tenant(s) as legal link between the parties to that agreement.

Where the use of inaccurate labels would elude non-waivable statutory provisions, those labels are stripped of their nominal effect and the agreement would be enforced as if it used the proper labels.

In the scenario you outline, *B* is in fact a tenant regardless of how he is labeled in the agreement. Landlord *A* cannot get away with violating *B*'s statutory rights under the pretext that pursuant to the agreement *B* is a subtenant rather than a tenant.